# Cmake issue with definitions

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, mingw

I currently try compiling library with CMake and MinGW32-make.
I obtain at start following errors :

g++.exe : error : /D: No such file or directory
g++.exe : error : WIN32: No such file or directory
... (and same errors with other values)

Why CMake pass /D WIN32 in MinGW instead -DWIN32 ?
For example : g++.exe (..) /D WIN32 /D BLABLA (..)

Thanks.

Comment: check your compile flags; g++ only does what you tell it to...

Comment: Can you show (the relevant part of) your CMakeList?

Comment: Use -D instead of /D for Visual Studio and gcc. It will work for both.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks, i changed it in notepad and it now works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CMake when you want to define a preprocessor macro that can be used in Visual Studio and other compilers its best to use -D instead of /D in your add_definitions() or the various CMake compiler flags variables. For example:

```
add_definitions(-DMYDEFINE)
```

I always do this even though most of my builds are under some version of Visual Studio.